# CakePHP: No error/success message appear

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP, and follow the tutorial of CakePHP to try login function, however there is no error message appear after I use the wrong username/password. Please help.

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user=$this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'bookmarks']);
        } 
        $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you included the Flash module in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

By using FlashComponent's magic method `__call()` an element is required to exist under **src/Template/Element/Flash**.

In your case you called `error()`, therefore it uses **src/Template/Element/Flash/error.ctp**. Make sure element exists.

Either that or you are not calling `$this->Flash->render()` in your view (where you want the error message to be shown).

Comment: I have checked, the element exists, but still cannot show error message